# change first element in list

Tags: android

How I can change buttontext of the first element in listview?

```
 View v = getListView().getChildAt(0 - yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
 Button Butt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine);
 Butt.setText("newtext");
```

This code crashes application.

Comment: Could you please show us the XML for R.id.buttonLine?

Comment: `<Button android:id="@+id/buttonLine" android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="Установить/Удалить" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

```
  // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
  // unneccessary calls
  // to findViewById() on each row.
  ViewHolder holder;

  // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
  // no need
  // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
  // supplied
  // by ListView is null.
  if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);

    // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
    // views
    // we want to bind data to.
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.buttonLine = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine);
    } else {
    // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
    // and the ImageView.
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  } holder.buttonLine.setText("Changed text of button"); 
  /////////////
  static class ViewHolder {
  TextView textLine;
  ImageView iconLine;
  Button buttonLine;
  TextView textTwo;

}
```

This code sets buttons texts one by one. You must just set some condition with if (for example if package installed set "Uninstall", and if not set "Install")
. With this code I can't set "second of first element". But I can add counter and check condition.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are passing to getChildAt(...) is always going to be negative, except when the position is 0. As a result, it will generally return null according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29). That null value will then crash when trying to use it with null.findViewById(...).

Try removing the

```
"0 -"
```

Comment: `View v = getListView().getChildAt(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition());
 Button someText = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine);
 someText.setText("Hi! I updated you manually!");// This doesnt works`

Comment: `<Button android:id="@+id/buttonLine" android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="Установить/Удалить" />`

Comment: Isn't the R.java generated at compile time? How would it know which instance of Button R.id.buttonLine corresponds to?

Comment: So I cant dynamically change elements?

Comment: Try adding some debug: `android.util.Log.e("List", String.valueOf(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition())); android.util.Log.e("List", String.valueOf(getListView().getChildAt(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition()))); android.util.Log.e("List", String.valueOf(R.id)); android.util.Log.e("List", String.valueOf(R.id.buttonLine)); android.util.Log.e("List", String.valueOf(v.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine)));`

Comment: It crashes on the line `View v = getListView().getChildAt(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition());` But when I comment that line (and your last that uses v.), it launches but I cant see output of android.util,Log. Logcat and Console are clean. Where can I see it?

Comment: View the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) for Filtering Log Output. I believe you want `adb logcat List:V`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, but you'll have to test it.

```
RelativeLayout listItem = (RelativeLayout)getListView().getChildAt(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition()); 
Button btn = (Button)listItem.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine);
btn.setText("Hi! I updated you manually!");
```

Basically, what you're getting from getListView().getChildAt() is the RelativeLayout object, defined in your XML as list item template. Then you get item number 2 from it - the third item defined, which is your Button.

Comment: Nope. It crashes again. Seems that app crashes on the second line of the code. Debugger says RuntimeException

Comment: I paste this code in the end of this section `@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Comment: Could you try then just 
`RelativeLayout listItem = (RelativeLayout)getListView().getChildAt(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition()); 
int cnt = listItem.getChildCount();`

Comment: And are you sure that your ListView has **at least one** item displayed? By an adapter or something?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I set adapter before this code `adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
 setListAdapter(adap);
 
 
 RelativeLayout listItem = (RelativeLayout)getListView().getChildAt(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition()); 
 int cnt = listItem.getChildCount();` Crashes again on the second line. I guess it crashes on the second line, because first line is incorrect.

Comment: Edited above to exchange `getChildAt` with `findViewById` (again), but this time called on the RelativeLayout and not on the ListView.

Comment: Again dont work. my main class extends ListActivity. I write this code after creation of adapter in onCreate section. I have some strings, to which list is connected. Am I doing everything right? Does your code works in test projects?